# SharePoint Online Export and Import Managed Properties

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, managed-property

is there a way to export/import managed properties in SPO using PowerShell? I looked around and it looks like there is no way of doing this via PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid we cannot export or import the managed properties in sharepoint online by PowerShell command.

It is by design.

Because in sharepoint online, we only can use the client-side object model.